# Is it unsafe putting the username and token in a "https" page route?

Tags: reactjs, security, routes, token, man-in-the-middle

I'm looking for the best practice and safe approach to handling a "renew-password" page in a SPA. The user will get redirected with "username" and a **temporary token** from the "login" page when his password is expired.
So far I found multiple options:

- Putting the username and token in query-string like: `/reset-password?username=test&token=jfF5$88F...`
- Putting the username and token in URL param like: `/reset-password/:username/:token`

Other options that aren't dealing with URL:

- Putting in pushState. in my case using react-router-dom: `history.push({ state: { username, token } })`
- Putting in Cookie or LocalStorage

But my main question is putting these data into the URL is safe or not? Can Man-In-The-Middle hijack the data even in "https" protocol?

Comment: yes, I would use the username as a payload in jwt along with other information

Comment: @Reza There is no jwt token because it was not a successful login. The token is a temporary token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually do not put secrets into URLs. The reason is, that every load balancer or proxy along the way is allowed to log URLs for debug reasons. We don't want our secrets to leak just because logs leaked.

There is one exception to this rule - when the secret is a one-time-only secret. When it is invalidated right after it is used. The reason for this exception is that there would be no other way of passing secrets over e.g. mails.

If HTTPS is done right nobody should be able to hijack the data. URL is part of the HTTP payload and will be encrypted whole if this is what you are concerned with.